# Create video at 1 fps

Tags: video, frame-rate, avconv

I have a sequence of files names `img-001.png`, `img-002.png` etc.
I want to assemble them into a video with only one image per second (fps=1). 
How can I do this with avconv ? I have tried using

```
avconv -i img-%03d.png -r 1 a.avi
avconv -i img-%03d.png -framerate 1 a.avi
avconv -i img-%03d.png -framerate 1 -r 1 a.avi
```

neither of these work properly. It seems that the video is produced at fps=24 and that it only takes `img-001.png` and `img-025.png` ... and skips every image in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
avconv -framerate 1 -i img-%03d.png -r 1 a.avi
```

(this syntax works with ffmpeg; should work here too)

Comment: Alright ! It works indeed. So the options have to be set in a particular order... this is odd. Many thanks.

Comment: `framerate` is specific to the image pipe demuxer so it goes before the image sequence input.